# How do I make use of serialized data from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How can I extract the serialized values of a string stored in MySQL? The values look something like this: `a:{s1:./... }`. What is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has a [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) function which turns any variable into a string like that.

```
echo serialize(array('foo', 3, array('bar' => 'BAR')));
// a:3:{i:0;s:3:"foo";i:1;i:3;i:2;a:1:{s:3:"bar";s:3:"BAR";}}
```

To return it to its original object, call [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize).

Answer (score 0):

[PHP::Serialization](http://search.cpan.org/~bobtfish/PHP-Serialization-0.33/lib/PHP/Serialization.pm) - simple flexible means of converting the output of PHP's serialize() into the equivalent Perl memory structure, and vice versa.

```
use PHP::Serialization qw(serialize unserialize);
my $encoded = serialize({ a => 1, b => 2});
my $hashref = unserialize($encoded);
```